# Get focus position after auto focus using v4l2

Tags: camera, v4l2

Its possible to get the focus position after a auto focus call with v4l2 (V4L2_CID_FOCUS_AUTO).

I know its possible to get the status (focused or not) using V4L2_CID_AUTO_FOCUS_STATUS, but I need the exact position after the auto focus.